# ngf-thumbnail not working in safari latest using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using `ng-file-upload` to upload the images using Angular.js. I am displaying image after upload using `ngf-thumbnail` but it's not working in safari and win-7.Its sometimes throwing the below error.

```
 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'FileAPI.readAsDataURL(file, listener)')
```

I am providing my code below:

```
<div>
<div ng-class="{'myError': billdata.upload_{{$index}}.$touched && billdata.upload_{{$index}}.$invalid }">
<input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="upload_{{$index}}" id="bannerimage_{{$index}}"  ng-model="mul.image" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-select="onFileSelect1($index);">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="mul.comment">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
 </div>
</div>
 <span class="input-group-btn" ng-show="mulImage.length>0">
<img ngf-thumbnail="mul.image" name="pro" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;" ng-if="mul.image !=null"><img ng-src="upload/{{mul.filename}}" name="pro" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;" ng-if="mul.filename!=''">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" ng-click="addNewImageRow(mulImage);" ng-show="$last"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="minus" id="minus" value="-"  ng-show="mulImage.length>1" ng-click="deleteNewImageRow(mulImage,$index);">

</span>
```

It's working in all other browser but not working in this environment.

Comment: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/818 looks some code needs to be included.

Comment: @MakarovSergey : i can not know which file need to include.I have included these files.`<script src="/spesh/js/FileAPI.js"></script>
    <script src="/spesh/js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
    <script src="/spesh/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>`.Still its not working. Can you please detect which file i am missing.

Comment: Actully no =( I have not used the library.

Comment: Do you know its solution ?

Comment: I am have what seems to be an identical problem.  Has anyone figured out the solution to this problem, by chance?